# Pass an array through .load

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, load

I have this jQuery code. What it does is that it gets values from (selected) radio buttons and then passes it in the 'c' array.

There are 40 items thus the `b<40` condition in the for statement. The next step that I'm doing is to pass it on PHP using `.load()`. As everybody can see in the code below, I am only in `c[3]`. Because on the way in I thought, maybe there's a way to pass this array without encoding them one by one.

So, is there a way to pass the array to PHP using `.load()` without encoding them one by one or am I just lazy?

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitexam', function() {
    var examinee = $('#examinee').val();
    var q1 = $('#QU1').attr('id');
    var c = ["null"];
    var b;
    for (b = 1; b < 40; b++) {
        c.push($('input[name=Q' + b + ']:checked').next('label:first').html());
        console.log(c[b]);
    }

    $('.bod').load('process.php', {
        examinee: examinee,
        a1: c[1],
        a2: c[2],
        a3: c[3],
        q1: q1
    })
});
```

Comment: so are you posting the data or getting ? can you post your html also

Comment: I am posting the data to the databse

Comment: you can check the answer, I already posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is only used for getting data from the server.

You are using a form, so you need to post the data to server using [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) or [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

[serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function is used to take all data from the form and convert it to string.

**jquery**

```
$(document).on('submit', '#submitexam', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize()).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

**html**

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" id="submitexam">
    all your radio buttons place it here and at the end instead of button use
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: i don't know how to say this, but i am not technically using the form tag. im just using a button and when it gets clicked, it gives me the variables. is that considered a form?

Comment: you should use a form to submit data, that is good practice. if you dont use form my solution won't work. place all your code inside a form

Comment: ok i am gonna try this once i get back to the office. meanwhile im still going to wait for some other answers. thank you very much!